# Auto code formatting in IntelliJ for Android xml files

Tags: intellij-idea

I just switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ and noticed that when I use "Reformat code" feature it  doesn't work like it is in Eclipse, i.e. it uses different number of spaces in my xml files. Is there a way to configure it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can change it in the XML code style settings:

[image]